# IE8 JQuery Disappearing elements issue (only working in quirks mode)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a website maintenance issue in IE8 only. The site runs fine in all other browsers including IE9 and IE10.

I can describe the issue best as follows:

In IE8 when the page is loaded, all the elements are displayed properly and everything looks great. However, when I activate a JQuery accordion, the entire page messes up. Here is what happens:

1)the page jumps upwards to a seemingly random location (this might be because the page is being resized according to the the size of the elements inside of the accordion.
2)the entire footer disappears, until I use the scrollbar down arrow, then it appears again.
3)all of the nav elements disappear until i hover over them, then they appear again.

If I open up the Developer Tools and change the document mode to Quirks, the page functions fine. And if AFTER that I change the document mode to Standards again, the page will function fine.. this problem is really weird and any input would be great.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle?

Comment: i need guidance on this.. is that the same thing as fiddler2?

Comment: Nope, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: ill try, but i dont think this is going to be reproduceable in jsfiddle. it will probably work just fine. let me see what i can do. its very strange and only in IE8....

Comment: We definitely need to see some kind of code in order to help here. A fiddle would be great, or even just post the relevant code in the question. In the meanwhile, can you confirm what version of jQuery you're using?