# IE8 Document mode issue

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Earlier today I asked a question and since then I have made a bit of progress in diagnosing the problem and have narrowed down the issue a little further. Here is the original question: [IE8 JQuery Disappearing elements issue (only working in quirks mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864718/ie8-jquery-disappearing-elements-issue-only-working-in-quirks-mode?noredirect=1#comment26083510_17864718)

So, I realized that the document mode is important and I inserted the following line to force IE8 to render the page in IE9 mode:

```
    < meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

This begs the question: What if the person is actually using IE8 (and not IE9 or IE10 and merely switching the browser mode through the Developer Tools?

I still need to make sure that the document is being rendered properly. Does anyone know what measures I can take to make this happen?

Comment: Er... it would seem strange that IE8 would know how to render pages like IE9...?

Comment: Try this: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> and if that doesn't work read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode

Comment: Have you tried using `IE=edge`? It forces IE to use the highest rendering engine available to that particular version.

Comment: You might ask Superman to fly around your website super fast counter-clockwise and get IE8 to act like it's 3 years in its future.

Comment: Does it also override IE10's dev tools to view in older browser modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like AKA states, add the meta-tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Also, to get a true browser experience, as opposed to IE9's interpretation of IE8 standards, you could set up a number of virtual machines on your PC and install the older versions of the browsers from [somewhere like this site](http://www.oldapps.com/internet_explorer.php)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you will often not realize which functions and tags are deprecated in ie8 until you test them yourself. Making your website compatible with older versions of IE is the bane of many programmers' existence.

Hit f12 in IE to open developer console and switch to IE8 mode to test it on your machine.
Some websites have different versions of their site for different browsers. Usually I do something like:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
<![endif]-->
```

You just have got to test. Also collect data on what browsers your users use most frequently will help determine how far back you should reasonably go.